# Image shows 1 thing, but queried data shows another when loading a website

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer

I was trying to query a website: `const url = "https://personal.vanguard.com/us/FixedIncomeHome"` with the hope to automate some functionality within puppeteer.

I noticed if i create a screen shot: `page.screenshot("preclick.png")` it will show the page data with tabs.  When i try to follow it up with a query, it seems to not return the second tab (denoted by the following selector: `a[container="CD"]`

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'})
page.screenshot("start.png")
page.evaluate( () => {
    document.querySelectorAll("a[container='CD']")[0].click()
})
///...
```

and i dont really know why this is the case.  Ideally, i am trying to click CD and then click an empty search.  I noticed that since session ids are tracked, I wanted to do this as a sort of E2E test in order to get the resulting table data.

I see that the Content of tab etc is dynamically loaded, so somehow there is an issue with the page being able to query.

I was attempting something else to see what would occur, waiting for the tag to appear, BUT it would just timeout after 30 seconds:

```
await page.waitForSelector("a[container='CD']").then( async resolve => {
     page.execute( () => document.querySelector("a[container='CD']").click() );
});
```

I dont know why the screenshot shows the HTML, but when attempting to query for it from within execute it fails.  It doesnt make sense to me why this occurs.  Ideally, I want to click CD tab, then i want to click Search, then i want to loop through the 20 results in the table.

*EDIT* I was noticing that evaluate was not querying the component correctly because of an iframe.  If i want to develop e2e testing though, i assumed there was a way to somehow get a reference to the button and click it, or simulate a click.*

Comment: Even it could be little tricky to get it work, I would recommend you debug under user session (not in headless mode). I solved similar issue and you need to find out whats happeing there (console, etc). Also networkidle2 means "there are no more than 2 network connections for at least 500 ms" which is not safe. I use networkidle0 to make sure that there are no connections at all.

Comment: I was running it NOT in headless to see how the evaluate was working.  I was noticing that the document is correct, but until I inspected the page, the query selector was not returning the information.  It seems there is a discrepency with what is reference in the doc and what is in code

Comment: I was hoping that there is a way to do some sort of "update" to re quantify the document object.

Comment: It does look like it there is an Iframe which is inhibiting the document query commands but i was thinking that with puppeteer i could query it as if it were XML or something in order to process.  It seems that burying into the nested iframes may be causing issues like Cross Origin stuff.  Even if this were Cross Origin, i would have thought that i could use Puppet to do E2E testing in order to execute clicks

Comment: Note I didnt executed js on page so now Im looking at API doc and there is no  `page.execute`. I can find only `page.evaluate` method. Where did you get that? And `document.querySelector("a[container='CD']").click()` works in your console right? There should be some error atleast, if not you should log every step.

Comment: @bigless  thats my bad.  I am using evaluate.  let me correct that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `iframe` from a selector. As the `iframe` has the ID `TWRIFrame`, you can wait for that selector, then get the [contentFrame](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#elementhandlecontentframe)  from that element.
Once you have the frame, the [frame class](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#class-frame) has almost the same functions as the page class, e.g. `click`.

Notice that, as that iframe is from other domain, with the `--disable-features=site-per-process` flag.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, args: ['--disable-features=site-per-process']});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://personal.vanguard.com/us/FixedIncomeHome', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
await page.screenshot("start.png");
await page.waitForSelector('#TWRIFrame');
const frameElement = await page.$('#TWRIFrame');
const frame = await frameElement.contentFrame();
await frame.click("a[container='CD']");
```

Comment: This works for you?   It seems thaat I get a UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:  No node found for selector: `a[container='CD']`

Comment: it did work for me. Maybe adding a waitForSelector before?